# .tab-current CSS definition

Tags: html, css

I am pretty new to CSS. There seems to be a ton of properties and values and it is a bit overwhelming. I am currently trying to emulate a stylesheet I found online. I am currently stuck on this portion

```
.tabs nav li.tab-current {
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

I understand `.tabs` is class and `.tabs nav` is the nav within where the tabs class I used in the html page. Same goes for `li`. I'm not sure what the `.tab-current` means and how it is being used. I'm not sure where to look to find notes/documentation on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure looks something like this

```
<div class="tabs">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="tab-current">Hey</li>
            <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I just added the `ul` tags in there since most li tags are found within them.

Anyway, the `li.tag-current` part of the selector just means that it's going to select the `Hey` and style it.

From the looks of it the `tab-current` class acts much like an `active` class you'd put on a list item or a menu item to show that it's the currently selected item.

Answer (score 1):

li.tab-current means li element with class tab-current.

So basically your CSS rule will be applied to all li tags with class tab-current being inside nav elements which are inside elements with class tabs